# An unknown band appearing in my gel electrophoresis

Tags: genetics, gel-electrophoresis

I am having trouble understanding what is the source of band "2" in the following gel-electrophoresis:

[image: Gel]

In this experiment, we took an E.coli transformant colony and ran its nucleic acids in the gel, after adding a restriction enzyme which cuts the recombinant plasmid molecule into two corresponding bands ("3" and "5" ["5" is very weak in the scanned version, but is well seen in the "hard copy" )  . I know the first line ("1") corresponds to possible genomic DNA we took from untransformed bacteria, and that the fourth line ("4") corresponds to a plasmid molecule without an insert. 6 is also well understood.

My question is- 
What is the source of band "2" which contains more base pairs than any of the parts of the plasmid and its insert , and in particular more base pairs than the insert?

WIll someone please help me understand this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need some controls. If you can purify the plasmid away from the genomic DNA, run that plasmid alongside this lane. Would also be good to have genomic DNA without plasmid, such as from your untransformed control, in another lane. This should tell you if the mystery band is from the plasmid or the genome. If it's plasmid DNA, are you sure you're getting complete digestion? Uncut plasmids usually produce more than 1 band because supercoiled DNA migrates at a different rate than open circle, which is different from linear. Incomplete digestion could have left supercoiled and circular.

Comment: Hi user137, thanks for your answer, as for your suggestions:
1. I ran four transformed colonies in four different lanes, and this is the only lane when this mysterious line appears, so I guess the problem is not incomplete digestion. 
2. I currently have no possibility of redoing this experiment with other controls. I am sure about the bands I told about, but still have no idea about this one. 

As mentioned here:
http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19114/why-isolated-recombinant-plasmid-dna-without-any-restriction-is-often-detected

the circular form should run a little bit

Comment: less fast than the linear one, so I don't think it is reasonable that this line corresponds to a circular plasmid, since "4" is the line corresponding to a linear plasmid without an insert. 

WIll you please help me figure it out ? 

Thanks a lot !

Comment: So you combined different plasmid digests with genomic DNA from different samples of bacteria and ran it all in 1 lane? Please describe the digestion in more detail. Band 4 is empty vector, but what are bands 3 and 5?

Comment: I would also suspect single cut DNA here. Can you give us some details on the digest?

Comment: OK. I took a plasmid (containing one restriction target for BamHI) and an insert (containing one more restriction target for BamHI) , and inserted it into E.coli bacteria. I then put the bacteria on a selective bed, and took a colony, homogenize it and then ran the nucleic acid part in electrophoresis. Just notice, that on the bed , around the main colony, I had very small colonies corresponding to non-transformant bacteria that are able to grow only because they feed from the food the main colony is providing them. 

As I said before, bands 3 and 5 are the two restrictions products I get

Comment: after digesting the plasmid+insert with BamHI. 

Got any idea?

Comment: The most likely explanation I can think of for band 2 is an incomplete digestion, that the BamHI is missing one of the cut sites and creating a linear plasmid that is longer than band 3 because it also contains band 5. Without further controls I can't really know. And was the selective media using an antibiotic such as ampicillin or kanamycin? Because if so the satellite colonies aren't eating food from the transformed colony, they are surviving in the antibiotic depleted region around the main colony.

Comment: Can you put up the plasmid map?